# rep for judging example questions instead of for posing them

Tags: feature-request, area-51, example-questions

Currently area51 is overrun by proposals and questions that are sometimes not of very high quality. I think the problem is, many are addicted to the rep-system (I won't even exclude myself) and therefore try to ask as many "good" questions as possible even on proposals they are not following. As a result there are too many questions to be judged with just 5+5 votes.

I make the numbers up, but basically:

I propose posing questions costs 5 rep which will be refunded as soon as 5 votes prove its usefulness (may also be mixed e.g. 3 on-topic 2 off-topic votes) and be rewarded with 10 rep as soon as the on/off-topic-status is determined. Voting for questions for a followed proposal should gain 1 rep per vote, maybe 2 rep if the question has less then 10 votes or is not clearly on-/off-topic yet¹. The amount of proposals that can be followed should also be limited (or at least how many can be joined per week).

¹ the latter might cause people to vote in such way that already clear questions become instable, so some anti-seesaw-mechanism would need be made up,too

**edit** (thx Arlen) Some way to gain much rep has to be provided to relieve the moderators, as Arlen [pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52937/rep-for-judging-example-questions-instead-of-for-posing-them/52938#52938). So 5 rep points per vote despite the question already being clear in its topic-ness should be needed. And maybe multiplying all rep-#s by 10. Of course this whole suggestion requires the voting limit to be relieved, plus it'd make the meh-vote obsolete (everyone disagreeing with the question could ignore it knowing the poser has -5 rep for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would not really work as the appointed moderators would never get relieved by new mods joining.

Comment: thanks, you're so right, I edited my suggestion including your answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we need to make the meh-vote obsolete.  It's important to let people know that there is a third alternative.

Comment: true, and that is not the essence of my suggestion, just a possible addition

Comment: Definitely.  "meh" may be unfortunately named, but it serves an important purpose.